# Is "actually" an example of pejoration?

Tags: terminology

Is the word "actually" an example of pejoration? When someone says "it's not actually" to counteract something negative someone says about them it can connote a little cheekiness and yet the denotation of actually is really an "actual or existing fact; really" (Dictionary.com).

Comment: Well, actually, that's an interesting question.

Comment: Would you say that if you'd looked in other dictionaries (eg [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/actually)) you'd have amended '[**the**] denotation of _actually_ is really an "actual or existing fact; really'? And would 'mild cheek' be a clearer term than 'pejoration' here?

Comment: The pragmatic marker usages of 'actually' are complex in themselves, and only overlap to a moderate degree with the 'actual or existing fact; really' sense. 'Actually, he's not all that bad' shows a hedging (gently correcting [in the speaker's opinion]) usage. 'Did he actually say that!?' is largely an invective marker usage, but obviously with a semantic overlap. Sometimes, only tone can identify the intended usage. As with 'Please ...'.

Comment: In "Actually, he's not that bad" is _actually_ a hedge? It announces, rather than blunts the subsequent contrary opinion, though it does, of course, delay it.

Comment: @KarlG Compare / contrast "Actually, he's not that bad" with "He's not that bad" when both are used as correctives (obviously to something like 'He's useless!') The second is starker, uncushioned.

Answer (score 1):

Pejoration as [semantic change](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_change) occurs when the meaning of a word moves from positive/neutral to negative. *Awful* once meant "full of awe," while among young Americans *awesome* has precipitously dropped in register and can now express momentarily enthusiastic approval, say, for a new kind of Pringle.

*Awful* is a clear case of pejoration, but despite the semantic weakening, slang *awesome* is still something positive, if far less grand, i. e., a reduction in quantity, but not quality.

The (mostly) British reduction of *[actually](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/actually?s=t)* to a filler word of mild emphasis is a similar reduction: it still means "in actual fact, really," it just does so with a quieter voice.

The effect is similar to what psychologists call [semantic satiation/saturation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_satiation), which describes the effect of repeating a word so often in sequence that it no longer conveys any meaning at all. This effect, however, is temporary. Once a word becomes mere filler, however, it probably won't ever recover its full voice.